# If we know about the divisors of $n$, what can we comment about the divisors of $n+x$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, divisor-sum, divisor-counting-function

I was dealing with a different problem when this question struck me-

> Let us have a natural number $n$, and we know that the divisors of $n$
> are $d_1,d_2,\dots d_k$. Now, we add any other $x\in \mathbb N$ to $n$
> and get a natural number $y=(x+n)$. What can be said about the
> divisors of $y$ (let's say $d_1^{\prime},d_2^{\prime}\dots
>  d_{k^{\prime}}^{\prime}$). Can we relate the $d_i$'s with the
> $d_j^{\prime}$'s? If not, then what extra information do we need?

I searched for an answer online, but nothing significant popped out. When I started thinking about it, I realised that there are a few obvious answers like "$n$ and $x$ are of the same parity if and only if $y$ is divisible by a positive power of $2$" or "$y$ must be divisible by the greatest common divisor of $n$ and $x$". But, I can't think of anything more concrete. I also tried to use the divisor counting and the divisor sum function, but that didn't help either.

Also, the last line in the question (i.e., *what extra information do we need*) may be met with "we need to know the exact value of $x$". But, of course, I want to minimize the number of requirements.

So, can anybody help me to have a detailed study of this idea? I still can't believe that nothing about this is (easily) available. I'm sure, people must have thought about this before. So, if anybody is aware of any such researches, please inform.

**Edit:** After reading the comments, I wanted to specify some particularities-

**1.** I already mentioned that I want something more than the trivialties of if $d|y$, then $d|n \iff d|x$. user2661923 asked for the divisors of $x$ or the intersection of divisors of $n$ and $x$. We can assume that the intersection is empty- that's the case I'm most interested in. Even if we have an intersection, can we say anything more than "all elements of the intersection divides $y$"? As Arthur pointed out, even relating the divisors of $n$ and $n+1$ seems to be extremely difficult. Also, even if we take two primes $p_1$ and $p_2$ (so that we need to deal with the least number of divisors), can we say anything about the divisors of $p_1+p_2$?

**2.** About the question by RoddyMacPhee, what I mainly want is to find a relation between the divisors of $y$ and the divisors of $n$. If that's not directly possible, I want to know what are the minimal requirements to get to such a relation. Or is it that divisors are so faithful towards multiplication that addition just randomly shuffles them without any significant mathematical relation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127221/discussion-on-question-by-sayan-dutta-if-we-know-about-the-divisors-of-n-what).

Comment: Questions like this are what topics like the ABC conjecture try to reason about: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture

Comment: Here's a method that uses factoring of $N-1$ to factor $N$. It can be easily extended to using any $N-x$ or $N+x$ to factor $N$.  
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4810956/can-factoring-90-help-factor-91

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "Let us have a natural number n, and we know that the divisors of n are d1,d2,…dk. Now, we add any other x∈N to n and get a natural number y=(x+n). What can be said about the divisors of y (let's say d′1,d′2…d′k′). Can we relate the di's with the d′j's? If not, then what extra information do we need?"

**Answer:** Let $n:=p_1^{l_1}\cdots p_k^{l_k}$ where the $p_i$ are distinct prime numbers and $l_i \geq 1$. Let $y:=q_1^{a_1}\cdots q_m^{a_m}$ where the $q_i$ are distinct prime numbers and $a_j\geq 1$ and with $x:=y-n >0$. It follows you may construct any such $y$ by adding a natural number $x$: There is by construction an equality $n+x=y$.

**Example:** As an example: $l=2, p_1:=2,p_2:=3$ and $n:=2^a3^b$. Let $3<q_1< \cdots <q_{10000}:=q_l$ be a set of 10000 distinct prime numbers larger than $3$ and let $y:=q_1^{a_1}\cdots q_l^{a_l}$ for some integers $a_i \geq 1$. The number $x:=y-n$ is a natural number and $y=x+n$. Is there a relation between $n$ and $y$? It seems not - you may choose arbitrary distinct prime numbers $q_i\notin \{2,3\}$, and the number $y$  will not be "determined" by the prime numbers $2,3$.

Comment: Nah the possibilities are set out by $n$ and $x$ as they'll have to be additive inverses modulo any divisors of $y$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee - write a detailed post where you explain this.

Comment: What detail it's just $n+x\equiv 0\pmod{d^{\prime}_j}$ now take away either of $n,x$ away from both sides.